# Initializing Prefab properties in standalone Unity applications

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my main scene, I have *Prefab* element that is configured by a number of properties. For example, one property identifies the IP address of a server that the application needs to connect to.

When I run the application in the editor, I can enter an IP address for the property in the *Prefab*'s *Inspector* view, and everything is fine. But if I build and run the application as a *WebGL* or *Windows* application, these *Prefab* properties are undefined, and do not use the values from the *Inspector* window.

How can I initialize *Prefab* properties in such a case, or pass the required information when starting the application?

Comment: Add default values to your data and save the prefab with them set. You could also use something like a ScriptableObject to hold that data and then push those values into the prefab when it is instantiated..